# Android bundle value is null when recyclerview excutes number of times based on the number of items

Tags: java, android

```
public class StylistFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static String docid;
    CircleImageView stylistImg;

    public StylistFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.stylist_recycler, container, false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.stylistRecycler);
        stylistImg=view.findViewById(R.id.stylistImg);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            docid=bundle.getString("userdocumentid","");
            Log.d("selectedDocumentId",docid);
        }
        try{
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            try {
                db.collection("stylist").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            try {
                                ArrayList<String> stylistId=new ArrayList<>();
                                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                                    String id=documentSnapshot.getId();
                                    stylistId.add(id);
                                }
                                StylistAdapter listAdapter = new StylistAdapter(task,docid,stylistId,stylistImg);
                                RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecorator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.divider));
                                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
                                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

}



    // here is recycler adapter

    public class StylistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

        private final Task<QuerySnapshot> task;
        private String documentid;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>allServices=new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> stylistId;
        private CircleImageView stylistImg;


        public StylistAdapter(Task<QuerySnapshot> task, String id, ArrayList<String> stylistId, CircleImageView stylistImg) {
            this.task = task;
            this.documentid=id;
            this.stylistId=stylistId;
            this.stylistImg=stylistImg;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleritem, parent, false);
            return new listViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            String imageUrl = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(position).getString("imageUrl");
            String firstName = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(position).getString("firstName");
            String lastName = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(position).getString("lastName");
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(((listViewHolder) holder).stylistImg);
            ((listViewHolder) holder).stylistname.setText(firstName);
            ((listViewHolder) holder).lastnameTv.setText(lastName);
            ArrayList<String> serviceDetails = (ArrayList<String>) task.getResult().getDocuments().get(position).get("services");
            allServices.add(serviceDetails);
            ((listViewHolder) holder).ChooseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybutton);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return task.getResult().getDocuments().size();
        }

        private class listViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private TextView stylistname,lastnameTv,specialist;
            private ImageView stylistImg;
            private Button ChooseBtn;

            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            public listViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                stylistImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stylistImg);
                stylistname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.StylistTv);
                lastnameTv =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastnameTv);
                specialist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.specialistTv);
                ChooseBtn =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.chooseBtn);
                ChooseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ChooseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectedbutton);
                try {
                  ServiceCategoryFragment servicesFragment = new ServiceCategoryFragment();
                    Bundle stylist = new Bundle();
                    stylist.putString("stylistfname", task.getResult().getDocuments().get(getAdapterPosition()).getString("firstName"));
                    stylist.putString("stylistlname", task.getResult().getDocuments().get(getAdapterPosition()).getString("lastName"));
                    stylist.putString("stylistImg", task.getResult().getDocuments().get(getAdapterPosition()).getString("imageUrl"));
                    stylist.putString("stylistid",stylistId.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    stylist.putStringArrayList("serviceid",(ArrayList<String>)task.getResult().getDocuments().get(getAdapterPosition()).get("services"));
                    stylist.putString("documentid",documentid);
                    servicesFragment.setArguments(stylist);
                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, servicesFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }*
```

I am getting bundle value from previous fragment.I am passing the bundle value to recycler adapter.The issue is when recyclerview excutes first time bundle value is available.If the recycler view executes more than one time there is no value in the bundle its giving null value.I want to use the id in next fragment.

Comment: Define String id globally.

Comment: no its not working i tried

Comment: please add your `fragment`  and `adapter` code to question

Comment: post here your adapters code, it will be more easy to help

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: please  add full  code of your fragment in question

Comment: What are you getting in Log.d() ?

Comment: i am getting the value which i passed in previous fragment

Comment: I think there is no string you are putting in bundle named "userdocumentid" so try to check             docid=bundle.getString("userdocumentid","");

Comment: Then why the value is coming first time

Comment: Please tell me one thing are you are coming back from `ServiceCategoryFragment` to `StylistFragment` By using `Fragment Transcation` ?

Comment: i am having three fragments in third fragment i am having one button there i am setting values in bundle. if i click the button it will redirects the page to first fragment.In first fragment i am getting that bundle value

Comment: earlier its worked but i don't know what happened its not working now

Comment: You need to pass bundle from everywhere.  From where you are  making `Transcation` to `StylistFragment`

Comment: make your   docid string private. like as   `private String docid;`

Comment: i used private its not working